# Can't click the icon in Bottom Navigation in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I just want to ask why my bottom navigation icons won't navigate if clicked exactly on the icon but it will navigate outside the border width of the button.

Here's the image of my bottom navigation and you can see it has a borderWidth
around it.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Here's my code for navigation:

```
<NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={({route}) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
              let iconName;

              if (route.name === 'Home') {
                iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home';
                color = focused ? 'primary' : 'basic';
              } else if (route.name === 'Details') {
                iconName = focused ? 'search' : 'search';
                color = focused ? 'primary' : 'basic';
              }

              // You can return any component that you like here!
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity style={{borderWidth: 2}}>
                  <Button
                    status={color}
                    appearance="ghost"
                    accessoryLeft={<Icon name={iconName} />}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            },
            tabBarActiveTintColor: 'tomato',
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
            tabBarShowLabel: false,
            headerShown: false,
          })}>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

TouchableOpacity has a property called onPress you use that for navigation and clicking/touching.